# D3: Text element drawn last but overlapped by some other elements

Tags: d3.js

here is a snippet of code:

```
var nodeGroup = svg.selectAll("g")
                 .data(listNodes)
                 .enter()
                 .append("g")
                 .attr("id",function(d){ return "Group_" + trimWhitespace(d); })
                 .attr("transform","translate(580,260)");

visualizeNodes(nodeGroup, coordinates);
visualizeConnections(nodeGroup, listEdges, coordinateDict);
visualizeText(nodeGroup, coordinates);
```

I visualize the text last but it still seems to be overlapped. It's over the circles drawn by visualize Nodes, but the multiple opaque lines drawn by visualizeConnections overlap it.

Comment: The asynchronous nature of javascript is tricky. If all elements are tied to the same dataset, it is easier (and perhaps more efficient) do to everything in a single chain.

Comment: So would it look something like nodeGroup.append("circle").attr(1).attr(2).append("text").attr(1).attr(2).append("rect").attr(1).attr(2)?

Comment: Your mileage may vary; try it and if it works, answer your own question.

Comment: I asked b/c I tried it and nothing happened. There's also quite a bit of code between the appends so it doesn't seem like the canonical method.

Comment: Hard to give advice without more information. A jsfiddle with minimum reproducible case would help to get a better answer.